# Is it dangerous to run git push heroku master too many times in a short period

Tags: heroku

I have been testing some viewport issues for mobile and probably ran

```
git push heroku master
```

about 50 times in the last 3 hours.  I am now seeing from the google speed tests that:

> Reduce server response time In our test, your server responded in 8.9
>   seconds. There are many factors that can slow down your server
>   response time. Please read our recommendations to learn how you can
>   monitor and measure where your server is spending the most time. Hide
>   details

This wasn't popping up earlier this morning and was under .5 seconds.  Did I damage one of my dynos on the heroku servers?=  My site isn't really getting any traffic yet so I haven't been doing any stage testing.

What is the best way to test production?
I was reading through this but was wondering if there is a better way to test production quickly.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with pushing many times in a row, but every time you push, your dynos will cycle.  This takes something like 5 to 15 seconds depending on the size of your slug.

Generally this means that the first query sent to your app at the moment your dynos are cycling might hang for about that long.  If Google checked your server's speed at that time, then that explains the response time.  However, there shouldn't be any lasting effects after you finish pushing repeatedly.

If I recall correctly there is a Heroku labs option to cycle dynos to eliminate this pause, basically taking down some of your dynos and then cycling them while the other ones are still up, but I do not recommend using it as it makes code pushes very unpredictable and can result in two versions of your app being live at the same time.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Things look good this morning and I dont see the server response warning